# Smooth circular animation in html list

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have html list ,  want to animate it left to right , but when it reach at the last point , it should rotate to its first position. Want only to show 3 elements is mandatory.

Current behavior : It is not circular.

I have tried this

```
var $elements = $("#itemsListBox ul li");
var count = $elements.length;

$('.pp_arrow_previous').bind('click',function(){

    total=(Math.floor(count/6))*480;
    var e=$('#slider').css("left");
    e=parseInt(e);
    e=Math.abs(e);

    if(e==0)

    {
        $('#slider').css({ position: 'absolute' });
        $('#slider').css({ left: -(total)+'px' });
    }
    else
        $('#slider').animate({left: "+=480"}, "fast");

    //alert("Slider left is : "+e);

});

$('.pp_arrow_next').bind('click',function(){

    var e=$('#slider').css("left");

    total=(Math.floor(count/6))*480;
    e=parseInt(e);
    e=Math.abs(e);
    if(total<=e)
    {
        $('#slider').css({ position: 'absolute' });
        $('#slider').css({ left: '0px' });

    }
    else
        $('#slider').animate({left: "-=480"}, "fast");

});
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AtweK/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check you current position before animate your slide.

```
var item_count=8;
var item_per_page = 3;
var translate_step = parseInt(item_count/item_per_page);

$('#leftArrow').on("click", function() {
    if($('#slider').css('left') == -translate_step*288+'px') {
        $('#slider').animate({left: 0}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#slider').animate({left: "-=288"}, 500);
    }
});

$('#rightArrow').on("click", function() {
    if($('#slider').css('left') == '0px') {
        $('#slider').animate({left: -translate_step*288}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#slider').animate({left: "+=288"}, 500);
    }
});

$('#resetBtn').on("click", function() {
    $('#slider').animate({left: "0"}, 500);
});
```

and this is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9chi/AtweK/7/)

Comment: Thanks , but when i click on left / right button continuously it misbehaves.

Comment: there is many solution to this problem, you can make button disabled until animation finish for exemple, or create variable to check if it's there is no animation in progress then (doAnimation) else return false ...

Answer (score 1):

SEE THE [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AtweK/6/)

Basically, for giving circular effect, you need to place a check, that sees whether the slide's current Left position is totally below(less) than window or slide's current Left position is totally above(more) than (window + windowWidth), when either of the cases get true, you set the slide left accordingly (without animation)

For making a carousel like slideshow, and an elegant one, you should consider few things :

- Window Width - the window going to show the slides
- Slider Total Width - you need to have total width of slider(with all slides)
- Frame Width - width of a single slide
- Left of the Window, Current Left of the Slide
- You should place check, that left or right of the slides should not increase infinitely.
- As soon as your slider reaches one extreme, immediately set its left to corresponding extreme

below I've made a super simple(ignoring too many smoothing aspects) sample, its not full-fledged, but serves your requirement :

**script:**

```
<script>
    var sWidth = $('#slider').width();
    var wWidth = $('#itemsListBox').width();
    var fWidth = $('#slider li').width();
    function move(direction){
            var sOffset = $('#slider').offset();
            var wOffset = $('#itemsListBox').offset();
            var currentPosition = sOffset.left;

        switch(direction){
            case 'left':
                   if(sOffset.left+sWidth >= wOffset.left){
                      $('#slider').animate({left: "-=288"}, 500);
                   }
                   else{
                        $('#slider').css({left: wOffset.left + wWidth});
                   }
               break;

           case 'right':
                if(wOffset.left+wWidth >= sOffset.left) {
                     $('#slider').animate({left: "+=288"}, 500);
                }
                else{
                     $('#slider').css({left: -(wOffset.left +sWidth)});
                }
                break;

           case 'reset':
                $('#slider').animate({left: "0"}, 500);
                break;     
        }
    }
</script>
```

and your buttons are like :

```
 <button id="leftArrow" onclick="move('left');" class="fbtnFirst">Left</button>
 <button id="rightArrow" onclick="move('right');" class="fbtnLast">Right</button>
 <button id="resetBtn"  onclick="move('reset');" class="fbtnReset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least, your else statements are missing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  **[JQuery plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php)**,for smooth circular animation